# Is there a Label control in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a Label control in WP7? I don't mind recreating it from scratch, but I don't want to reinvent the lug nut if I don't have to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Labels are not supported, but you can use a [TextBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead. It's not a direct replacement, however, and [this post](http://xamlgeek.net/2009/06/08/silverlight-textblock-versus-label/) highlights some of the differences.

> Even though TextBlock lives in the System.Windows.Controls namespace,
>   it is not a control.  It derives directly from FrameworkElement. 
>   Label, on the other hand, derives from ContentControl.  This means
>   that Label can:
>
> 1. Be given a custom control template (via the Template property).
> 2. Display data other than just a string (via the Content property).
> 3. Apply a DataTemplate to its content (via the ContentTemplate property).
> 4. Do whatever else a ContentControl can do that a FrameworkElement cannot.
>
> But be aware! The use of Label is a way more heavy then TextBlock due
>   to its Visual Tree.  ...

Answer (score 1):

According to this [video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Video/gg241259) (0:52) Label is unsupported.